# Plist in reverse order

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, plist

I have Plist with list with List of Dictionaries(item0,item1,item2)..
generally when I display in screen ..it populates in ascending order...`item0 then item1 then item2......and so on`..I want the Plist to be display in reverse order as `itemn,itemn-1.........item2,item1,item0`

[image: first]
.

and this is how code goes...and How Can I reverse it ..need changes in `Array` below

```
NSMutableArray *Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self readFromPlist]];

NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i< [Array count]; i++)
//how to reverse by making changes here
//for (int i =[Array count] ; i>0; i--) does not work
{


    id object = [Array objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;



           tempItemi  =[[ECGraphItem alloc]init];

        NSString *str=[objDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"str value%@",str);
        float f=[str floatValue];


        //my code here
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reverse enumeration

```
for (id someObject in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator]){
    // print some info
    NSLog([someObject description]);
}
```

For your code:

```
for (id object in [Array reverseObjectEnumerator]){
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;

        tempItemi  =[[ECGraphItem alloc]init];

        NSString *str=[objDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"str value%@",str);
        float f=[str floatValue];

        //my code here
    }
}
```

---

Also in your code:

```
//for (int i =[Array count] ; i>0; i--) does not work
```

should be as

```
for (int i =[Array count]-1 ; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: and is it possible..like from plist..I want to display for 1 week iteration ...means for date-26 Dec 2012 to 1 week

Comment: plists are stored as per key-value pairs, you can easily sort the dictionary or retrive it based on key or value...

Comment: for this case how I can i sort here..I am passing the `date` value as the NSDate in my app ..

Comment: explain your question, am not getting. Do you need code to sort nsdates?

Comment: ya...check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039913/how-to-sort-plist-by-its-value

Answer (score 1):

You are itrating from `count to 1` whereas array has objects from index `count-1 to 0`
e.g.
Array with `10` objects has objects from index `0` to `9`

```
for (int i =[Array count]-1 ; i >= 0; i--)
{
    id object = [Array objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;

        tempItemi  =[[ECGraphItem alloc]init];

        NSString *str=[objDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"str value%@",str);
        float f=[str floatValue];


        //my code here
 }
```

Comment: and is it possible..like from plist..I want to display for 1 week iteration ...means for date-26 Dec 2012 to 1 week