# How to sort plist by its value

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, sorting

I have Plist with list with List of Dictionaries(item0,item1,item2).and I populate this plist in the Graph..its works fine.and in Plist `key (date)-> Value(i store by using NSDate)` .Now I need to sort the Plist in such a way that:-
`graph` should display for only one week.
say if first value is `26-Dec-12` than only upto `1-Jan-13`(1 week) values plist should display

[image: first]
.

**code** :

```
- (NSArray *)readFromPlist
{
// get paths from root direcory
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"calori.plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];

valueArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

  return valueArray;
}
```

and

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code


    CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
ECGraph *graph = [[ECGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 480, 320) 
                                    withContext:_context isPortrait:NO];

NSMutableArray *Array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self readFromPlist]];


NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id object in [Array reverseObjectEnumerator]){

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;


           tempItemi  =[[ECGraphItem alloc]init];

        NSString *str=[objDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"str value%@",str);
        float f=[str floatValue];


        NSString*str1=[objDict objectForKey:@"date"];

        NSLog(@" str values2-- %@",str1);

        tempItemi.isPercentage=YES;
        tempItemi.yValue=f;

        tempItemi.name=str1;



         [items addObject: tempItemi];



    }
}

[graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Comment: update/correct your question :`say if first value is 26-Dec-12 than only upto 1-dec-12(1 week) values plist should display`

Comment: You want to sort or only show for 1 week?

Comment: ya right.....and what to change? isn't correct?

Comment: for 1 week? if first value is 26-Dec-12 upto 1-Jan-2013 should not be there?

Comment: in your readFromPlist, where is `return` ?

Comment: check now..by mistake I delete that return

Comment: Check my answer... and for any clarification comment in my answer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirement is to filter date within 7 days,

I am giving you a logic, try this way:

```
- (NSArray *)readFromPlistForOneWeek {

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"calori.plist"];


    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];

    //loop through each of the item
    //and check if <8 then add that keyValue to array
    NSMutableArray *tempValueArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *subDict in [dict objectForKey:@"title"]) {
       // NSLog(@"=> %@",subDict);

        NSString *plistDateString=[subDict objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy"];

        NSDate *plistDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:plistDateString];

        NSString *currentDateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

        NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [plistDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
        NSInteger dateDiff = secondsBetween / 86400;

        if( dateDiff<8 ){ //within 0-7 days
            [tempValueArray addObject:subDict];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"valuArray : %@",tempValueArray);

    return tempValueArray;
}
```

Comment: what should be the logic?? and dateDiff

Comment: error :- no know class method for string `dateString` in `NSDate *date2`

Comment: do some googling yaar, you are doing some small mistake... or if you want me to complete your code, then mail your project to me... find my email id in my profile.

Comment: what i did... NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
    
    NSDateFormatter *date=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [date setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy"];
    NSDate *date2 = [date dateFromString:date1] ;..this is what i was doing but not works

Comment: anyways check your mail id ...I have mailed you

Comment: ya its perfect..thank you very much..but small problem when i entered 25 dec,22 dec,20 dec ..it displaying..20dec

Comment: today is 26, so it wil display 18-26th of dec-12 record, is there any error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with NSSortDescriptor?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"DATE" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
[yourDictionary sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
```

Comment: no I have not tried..but how to use it and `compare:` function what should give in this

Comment: compare is predefined function for ios. You do not need to worry about compare function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfile" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    // sort it
    NSArray *sortedArray = [[myDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    // iterate and print results
    for(NSString *key in sortedArray) {
        NSLog(@"key=%@,value=%@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    }
```

Comment: what should be `(caseInsensitiveCompare:)` function

Comment: its a method from foundation framework of ios- (NSComparisonResult)caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)string; and this will compare two strings

Comment: ya but want it to display for only 7 days ..it won't work there ..i think